# HttpErrorResponse Unauthorized (401) Angular 8 With Laravel 5.8 and Passport Authintication

Tags: api, authentication, laravel-5, angular8, laravel-passport

I have create API on laravel 5.8 using passport Auth.
I have the following API routes on laravel :

```
// private routes
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/getUser', 'Api\AuthController@getUser')->name('getUser');
});

// public routes
Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->name('login.api');
Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register')->name('register.api');
```

**I test my routes using postman and that works!**
**but when I have call the routing from angular 8, the public routes works, but the private route return the error 401 (Unauthorized).**

[The error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRK6n.png)

> - GET http://localhost:8000/api/getUser 401 (Unauthorized) zone-evergreen.js:2952
> - ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:8000/api/getUser",
>     ok: false, …} core.js:6014

the following code for call the routes in angular:

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

headers: Headers = new Headers();
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getUser(accessToken) {
      this.headers.append('Accept','application/json');      
      this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      this.options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
      return this.http.get(this.urlServer, this.options);
    }
```

> I have tried a lot of way to solve this problem and see all tickets here,
>   but the issue not solved yet.

Comment: Are you injecting the correct `accessToken` from angular?

Comment: @NikolaGavric Yeah, I saved my accessToken in the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way to solve this problem...

> I change my way of request by import the old Http from angular/http
>   instead of HttpClient from angular/common/http..

so the new code of angular is :

`import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http } from '@angular/http';
 constructor(private http: Http) {}
 getUser(accessToken) {
 return this.http.get(this.server + 'getUser', this.options).pipe( map(res => res.json()));
}`